# defining extra paths in akka

Tags: javascript, html, css, akka

I am pretty new to akka. I have an html, css, jv template that I need to put up to our server.

```
package com.example
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.xml.ScalaXmlSupport.defaultNodeSeqMarshaller
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{ HttpApp, Route }

/**
 * Server will be started calling Server_HttpApp .startServer("localhost", 8080)`
 * and it will be shutdown after pressing return.
 */
object  Server_HttpApp extends HttpApp with App {

  def routes: Route =
    pathEndOrSingleSlash { // Listens to the top `/`
      complete("Helloo") // Completes with some text
    } ~
      path("hello") { // Listens to paths that are exactly `/hello`
        get { // Listens only to GET requests
          //complete(<html><body><h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1></body></html>) // Completes with some text
          getFromResource("src/abc/html/index.html")
        } ~
        getFromResourceDirectory("src")



      }

   startServer( "xyz" , 70)
}
```

How can i define the paths to CSS javascript and image files, which are under `src/abc/css`; `src/abc/jv`; `src/abc/images`.

I have seen some codes using prefix but wasn't able yet to use it properly.
Also, there are multiples images, should I declare them all? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `abc` directory to `src/main/resources` and do it like this. This is a full working example:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object WebServerHttpApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    def routes: Route = getFromResourceDirectory("abc") ~ pathPrefix("hello") {
      get {
        redirect("index.html", StatusCodes.PermanentRedirect)
      }
    }

    Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "localhost", 8000)
  }
}
```

Visiting `localhost:8000/hello` will redirect to `index.html` page and assets within `abc` directory can be included in that page.

Comment: actually this does not work, do you mind writing up the imports you use and the complete script? thnk you

Comment: would you know how to do the Post?